# SelectList not sorting at all

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, selectlist

```
public static SelectList HolidayDays()
{
    SelectList retval = GenerateKeyValueList<HolidayCity>(HolidayCityHelper.GetFriendlyName, HolidayCity.NotSet);

    //sort
    retval.OrderBy(i => i.Text == "New York")
          .ThenBy(i => i.Text == "London")
          .ThenBy(i => i.Text);

    return retval;
}
```

Why isn't the SelectList sorting at all? It stays in the same exact order that it is in before I even perform the sort operations, but it compiles and runs without error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) and [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535112.aspx) return a collection, which you're not setting to your return value;

---

```
SelectList retval = GenerateKeyValueList<HolidayCity>(HolidayCityHelper.GetFriendlyName, HolidayCity.NotSet);

return new SelectList(retval
        .OrderByDescending(i => i.Text == "New York")
        .ThenByDescending(i => i.Text == "London")
        .ThenBy(i => i.Text).ToList(), 
    "Value", "Text");
```

Comment: Hmm, now I seem to be getting this error: Error 7 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I casted it, but is that the right move?

Comment: Actually, this seems to be ordering everything fine, but then ENDING the list with "London, New York" instead of beginning the list with "New York, London". I can't figure that out.

Comment: Well if it was being reversed, wouldn't it put "New York, London" and then the rest in reverse alpha order? It's putting everything in alpha order and then adding "London, New York" at the end

Comment: what does: `retval.OrderBy(i => i.Text).ThenBy(i => i.Text == "London").ThenBy(i => i.Text == "New York")` give you?

Comment: When I reverse them like that, it actually puts London and New York into their correct places in the MIDDLE of the list. So it basically sorts the whole list as one big alpha sort, Instead of placing New York, London up top.

Comment: It looks right, but for some reason I'm not able to cast correctly. It says this Error 20 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: you must not have updated the `GenerateKeyValuePair<T>` EXACTLY like I specified.

Comment: So theres no way to go about this without updating that method?